# QLDB - Indexed Storage vs Journal Storage

Tags: amazon-qldb

As I am new to QLDB. I have some doubts

1. Why Indexed Storage consumes more size than Journal Storage?
2. During Large Data Insertion there is an increase in Journal Storage Size even after Insertion is Stopped for a certain Period.Can you explain me why?
3. What are the tables that are present in Index Storage along with current and History ?

Answer (score 1):

*Q1:* the Journal is conceptually similar to tape. It's really good (performance and cost) for sequential reads and writes, but poor for random access. This is why we use it to record transactions. Indexed storage is designed for random access, but this is simply more expensive to implement. We bill for them separately to keep the cost of QLDB as low as we can make it.

*Q2:* the Journal size will not (ever) increase unless you are committing transactions. You may be noticing this in CloudWatch Metrics, which may be delayed by a few minutes (or longer, depending on how you are aggregating the metrics).

*Q3:* that's it, just your data. QLDB also offers some virtual tables (such as `information_schema.user_tables`), but these are not "in indexed storage" - i.e. you're not paying for them.